# How to change a neural network to improve the accuracy on the validation set?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

We are using Tensorflow to train a binary classification image dataset with `700 images` where each image is `256*256*1` and the dataset is equally split to the two classes. We slightly changed the `Cifar10` model on `Tensorflow` and the code of our model could be seen below.

```
# conv1
with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',
                                     shape=[5, 5, 1, 256],
                                     stddev=5e-2,
                                     wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [256], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv1)

# pool1
pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                     padding='SAME', name='pool1')
# norm1
norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(pool1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                name='norm1')

# conv2
with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',
                                     shape=[5, 5, 256, 256],
                                     stddev=5e-2,
                                     wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(norm1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [256], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv2)

# norm2
norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(conv2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                name='norm2')
# pool2
pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(norm2, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                     strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool2')

# local3
with tf.variable_scope('local3') as scope:
  reshape = tf.reshape(pool2, [FLAGS.batch_size, -1])
  dim = reshape.get_shape()[1].value
  weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[dim, 384],
                                      stddev=0.04, wd=0.004)
  biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [384], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))

  local3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
  _activation_summary(local3)

# local4
with tf.variable_scope('local4') as scope:
  weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[384, 192],
                                      stddev=0.04, wd=0.004)
  biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [192], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
  local4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(local3, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
  _activation_summary(local4)

with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
  weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [192, NUM_CLASSES],
                                      stddev=1/192.0, wd=0.0)
  biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [NUM_CLASSES],
                          tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
  softmax_linear = tf.add(tf.matmul(local4, weights), biases, name=scope.name)
  _activation_summary(softmax_linear)
```

We use **batchsize = 2** and **learning rate = 0.005**.

Currently, the [loss](https://thumb.ibb.co/cnCnQk/dana11_lnx_1.png) and [validation accuracy](https://image.ibb.co/nN4Oy5/dana11_lnx_1.png) look like this. The max accuracy is bouncing between `65%` and `70%`.

What kinds of parameters should I change to get a higher accuracy? I tried to decrease the filter size to 3 and add two dropout layers (0.5) but it does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like your model is [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) on the training data. This means that your model is not generalizing well in terms of really learning the underlying concepts of the data, but just simply memorizing the 700 training images. It would be helpful to see an accuracy plot on your training data, which I suppose is somewhere in the range of 90% - 98%. Your loss function shows a very steep decrease while the accuracy on your validation set seems to plateau ~65%. This is a strong indicator for an overfitting model.

There are a couple of options to go for. First of all a training set of just 700 images is way to small in most cases, causing the network to memorize the data pretty fast. You should try to either gather more training data and/or to apply data augmentation to your training data to increase the total number of training images. This makes it harder for the network to memorize every single image and its correct label.

Furthermore you should apply [regularization operations](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#reg) ([lecture slides](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec9.pdf)) such as weigh decay (L1, L2 norm) or [Dropout](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf) to your model which help the network to generalize well onto the data.

Comment: I just ran a validation on 180 images of the training dataset. It is indeed 100%... So it is definitely overfitting. We have 350 images for each class and we have 2 classes in total. What would be an optimal number of images we need for each class? Thank you so much for your suggestions! They are extremely helpful.

Comment: That is not easy to say... The more the better, usually a couple thousand per class would be good. Keep in mind that in most cases you can increase the number of training images quite simple by applying data augmentation operations such as `horizontally flipping`, `random crops` or `color jittering` to each image. There are some very useful pre-implemented script which you can run over your dataset to augment it. Do not run the augmentation live before propagating them through your network, do this before the actual training an store them in an LMDB or HD5 database for quick access .